# Easy transcendence question over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $ M $ be a maximal ideal of $ \mathbb{C}[x_{1}, \dots ,x_{n}] $ and let $ \alpha \in \big(\mathbb{C}[x_{1}, \dots ,x_{n}]/M \big) \setminus \mathbb{C} $. I want to show that $ \alpha $ is transcendental over $ \mathbb{C} $.

Since $ \alpha \notin \mathbb{C} $, we can write $ \alpha=f(\overline{x_{1}}, \dots , \overline{x_{n}}) $ for some nonconstant polynomial $ f $. Supposing $ \alpha $ were algebraic over $ \mathbb{C} $, then there would exist a polynomial $ P(T) \in \mathbb{C}[T] $ such that $ P(f(\overline{x_{1}}, \dots , \overline{x_{n}})=\overline{0} $, but I don't know how to derive a contradiction from this though I know it must be simple.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the so-called fundamental theorem of algebra ?

Comment: Yes. So if $ \alpha $ were algebraic over $ \mathbb{C} $ then it would be a root of a complex polynomial which splits completely over $ \mathbb{C} $, so $ \alpha $ would be  in $ \mathbb{C} $ which is false. I guess it was a silly question after all. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. But if I were a teacher and had given you this exercise, I would have expected you to say that $\alpha$ must be one of these roots because $M$ is a maximal ideal, and thus $\mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]/M$ is a field, and thus an integral domain (because when $M$ isn't maximal, you can obviously sometimes find algebraic elements)

Comment: Just saying: If $\alpha$ is as described in the question, then $\alpha$ is a root of the zeta function with real part not equal to $\frac{1}{2}$.